# Can biometric photos / finger prints be forged when they are taken by a human?

Tags: biometrics

Imagine a scenario, where you have a person p online which has a very good profile. For example, you want to hire them. This person is identified by a public key and has some information I about him signed with this public key. However, there is no way of contacting this person.

Now somebody p' shows up and wants to prove that he is p. He does not have his computer with him, so he can't sign anything with his private key.

What would "I" have to be so that it is possible to identify him an make sure the person who is in front of you is not a swindler?

I thought maybe biometric photos could be something? I guess a human would easily see when you would try to wear a mask to pretend you are p?
I think I've seen that one can put something on the finger to get another fingerprint, so I guess finger prints are not a good identifier?
Are there other identifiers of a person which are hard / impossible to forge, without having to create a shared secret? (Note that in this scenario, the biometric data is public)

One identifier which cannot be forged is DNA. But getting the DNA data is also quite expensive / time consuming, I guess?

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure about the ability to see if someone is wearing a mask - there are some really realistic silicone masks available now. Similar techniques can result in very inconspicuous fake fingerprints too. I'd suggest taking a photo, giving them a copy on a USB stick/CD, and getting them to sign it with their private key and send it to you. Not perfect, but hard to fake!

Answer (score 1):

Even a DNA sample can be forced to be inaccurate: it's dangerous, expensive - but it's possible, beleive me. The way you're 100% sure that p and p' are the same person is sign something with *your* key, not giving any of keys to him, give this signed piece to him and ask him to sign with his key and bring the result with himself. You will be able to verify it in two ways: his signature **and** you can check the integrity of your initial crypto-message: the person "p" is not aware of what's inside, so it can't forge this. It should be fine and inexpensive, IMHO.

Comment: That alone is susceptible to MITM. The real p could attend an interview at t+1 where the hiring manager gives him _your_ paper asking him to bring back the decoded content. Which is then given back to you by p' If you **have** to avoid these threats (eg. youa re the NSA) you shall make it in such a way you can't be fooled even if the real p is interviewed by someone impersonating you.

Comment: You could end up with p "working" for NSA' and the insider p' at the real NSA. The piece may contain «This text along nonce j5n9p62QSzwsyQ… is to be used a proof that p was interviewed by Martin Thoma at 2016-05-07 16:28:56 UTC on X Street Nº 5, 2nd floor, and has to be returned signed by your  key 0x12345678 and encrypted to 0x87654321 and including…»  And even then, you are relying on the real p to notice that something in the text doesn't match should a MITM happen, instead of plainly following the instructions.